# Prove that the graph of a convex function is below the segment that joins two points

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

A function $f: [a,b] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is convex if for all $x_1,x_2 \in [a,b]$ with $x_1<x_2$ we have that

$\displaystyle\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2 -x_1} > \displaystyle\frac{f(x)-f(x_1)}{x -x_1}, \;\;\;\; \forall\;x\in[x_1,x_2]$.

A) Prove that if $f$ is convex, the graph of $f$ in $[x_1,x_2]$ is below the segment that joins $(x_1,f(x_1))$ with $(x_2,f(x_2))$

I have been trying to solve it by the Mean Value Teorem by considering a new function $g(x)=y-f(x)>0$, being $y$ the segment, but I'm lost and I don't know how to go on.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What you need to prove is exactly the inequality you already have. Just ask yourself what is the equation of the straight line passing through $(x_1,f(x_1))$ and $(x_2,f(x_2))$

Comment: The ecuation of the straight line is $y = f(x_1)+\displaystyle\frac{(f(x_2)-f(x_1))(x-x_1)}{x_2-x_1}$, but how do I continue? I have been trying to relate that equation with the inequality, but I don't know how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asked to show that for each $x$ between $x_1$ and $x_2$ the $y$ coordinate of the corresponding point on the  graph is less than nor equal to the $y$ coordinate  of the corresponding point on the line segment.  In other words you have to show that $f(x) \leq f(x_1)+\frac {(f(x_2)-f(x_1)(x-x_1)} {x_2-x_1}$. This is immediate from the  inequality in the definition.